# Can i distribute traffic between 2 servers

Tags: python

I have a server with a web front-end (WebServer). This WebServer makes a call to a service on another server (Server2). Due to heavy load I have added another instance of Server2 (Server3).

I want to distribute the load between Server 2 and Server 3. I know load balancers usually do this type of thing - but its not suitable in this scenario.

I want to add some logic on the webserver to distribute the load - something very simple.

Is there any python libraries out there that will do this?

I'm not really sure what I am looking for or what to Google.

Comment: Why not just send every other request to the other back-end server?

Comment: this is my backup plan, just want to make sure I'm not missing some great library everyone knows about except me.

Comment: You said, load balancers do it but it's not suitable, so I don't know what else great would you expect, even this "simple" solution can be view as a kind of load balancing.

Comment: Why not load balancing?

Answer (score 0):

I went with a custom round-robin type of thing in python - which was pretty easy.

```
SERVER1 = "http://172.18.128.24/Z/"
SERVER2 = "http://172.18.128.24/Z/"

import random
server = random.sample((CLEANSER1,CLEANSER2),1)[0]
```